# Labels in x86 assembly (AT&T syntax)

Tags: assembly, x86

I came across the following code :

```
.macro STAGE2
    /* Defined in the linker script. */
    mov $__stage2_nsectors, %al
    mov $0x02, %ah
    mov $1f, %bx   <----------------------
    mov $0x0002, %cx
    mov $0x00, %dh
    mov initial_dl, %dl
    int $0x13
    jmp 1f        <----------------------
    .section .stage2
    1:     <----------------------
.endm
```

Where the label `1` could have been a simple name like `my_label` as well, and then I could have done `jmp my_label`. But in the above code, why an `f` was appended in `jmp 1f`?

I tried fiddling the code to induce some errors to get to know what its called. I could get one of the following error :

```
main.S: Assembler messages:
main.S: Error: local label `"1" (instance number 2 of a fb label)' is not defined
```

Is this called as `fb` label? Initially I confused `1f` as a constant, but then I saw that `0x` prefix was missing in `mov $1f, %bx`, so it has to be label. Can someone please help me what its called and what are the rules around it?

Comment: Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27353169/2189500), `It branches to the first found label "x" searching "forward" for "f" or "backward" for "b".`

Comment: @usr2564301  : yes it does. Thanks. I could not find it because I did not know what to search for.